# Может ли НЕ сработать событие beforeunload в браузере?

Tags: javascript, события

beforeunload срабатывает при закрытии вкладки. Существуют ли какие-то обстоятельства, при которых это событие НЕ сработает? (кроме удаления обработчика события)

Задача - сделать учет открытых и закрытых вкладок в пределах одного домена для вебсокета, чтобы было только одно соединение (только с одной главной вкладки).

Comment: Крэш браузера? Отключение юзером js в табе?

Comment: в принципе да, креш браузера (или электричество отключили внезапно).
> Отключение юзером js в табе?
пусть тогда не жалуется, что что-то не так работает. И маловероятно.

Comment: @kanaris: Ну, это зависит от того, для чего вы используете фичу. Хотите _вы_, чтоб работало, или _пользователь_?

Comment: само событие в штатных обстоятельствах сработает всегда, но вот асинхронные вызовы из этого события могут и не сработать (setTimeout, например)